# SSH connection on a particular port throws an error

Tags: linux, ssh, gerrit

I am running `gerrit` on my `centos` virtual machine. I want to monitor the events on the port where `gerrit` is being run. The command for it is as follows,

```
ssh -p port host_ip gerrit stream-events
```

When I try to run this command I get below mentioned error,

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

But, to even clone projects on `gerrit` or push projects into `gerrit` it is necessary to have my `ssh` key setup on the `gerrit` instance and I am able to push and clone successfully from `gerrit`. My `known_hosts` file in the `.ssh` directory on my `centos` virtual machine is also setup for this port.

I am not able to even ssh into the port and host_ip. I get the same error when I run the following command,

```
ssh -p port host_ip
```

I am running the `ssh` command from the same host.

Is there something I am missing? Any other configuration I need to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're either using:

- different key for git and different for this ssh request
- different port in each case
- different host

There are no special options in git itself that would affect this connection normally. You could always try to run both the commandline ssh and the git one with -v option and compare outputs (what ciphers, keys, hosts, etc. are used).

Comment: I was not mentioning the right host. Instead of user@host_ip I was using just host_ip. Thanks!